# JS Depth First Traversal Pre-Order

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, depth-first-search

Just as an exercise, I am writing JavaScript to do a `pre-order` of `Depth First Traversal` on a Binary Search Tree.

Note: this is iteration, NOT recursion. I can do it recursively, but there are ways in Python to do it iteratively, so I want to see how this might work in JS.

My code is below:

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
    if(!root) return [];
    let stack = [root];
    let output = [];

    while(stack.length) {
        root = stack.shift();
        if(root !== null) {
            output.push(root.val);
            if(root.left !== null) stack.push(root.left);
            if(root.right !== null) stack.push(root.right); //Source of the issue
        }
    }

    return output;
};
```

Say the input is `[1,2,3]` this works just fine. However, there is a problem when an input is more diversified, like `[1,4,3,2]`, it returns:

`[1,4,3,2]`

instead of

`[1,4,2,3]`

Because when the engine hits the line of code labeled in the block above, it will iterate over the right:

```
     1
    / \
   4   3
  /
 2
```

So somehow, you have to inform the algorithm to keep iterating over every left until there is no more left, then iterate over the right. Recursively, this is pretty simple.

But using iteration, not so much.

What's bizarre to me is that a similar Python function will run just fine:

```
class Solution(object):
    def preorderTraversal(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        if root is None:
            return []

        stack, output = [root, ], []

        while stack:
            root = stack.pop()
            if root is not None:
                output.append(root.val)
                if root.right is not None:
                    stack.append(root.right)
                if root.left is not None:
                    stack.append(root.left)

        return output
```

Obviously, there is a difference in the languages that is causing an issue, or I have made a mistake somewhere in the algorithm.

Would anyone know what the difference is? I'm much more interested in understanding **why** instead of just a shortcut to make it work.

Comment: One thing that strikes right away is `shift` in js vs `pop` in python.

Comment: Bingo, I assumed pop() was equivalent to shift in JS but of course it's not, because JS has a pop() method. Now we have to reverse the order in which the code checks for right and left, and it will iterate over them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help in the comments, this was actually a simple misuse of the `pop` vs `shift` method.

Python is using `pop` whereas I was using `shift` in JS. But this means we have to reverse the direction in which we find the right values, and the left values.

So the JS code would actually be:

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
    if(!root) return [];
    let stack = [root];
    let output = [];

    while(stack.length) {
        root = stack.pop();
        if(root !== null) {
            output.push(root.val);
            if(root.right !== null) stack.push(root.right);
            if(root.left !== null) stack.push(root.left);
        }
    }   

    return output;
}
```